# Jquery Search String from span not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working with JQuery Filter and I am facing issue while searching string in span.

Following is the Search function which I am using:

```
function searchAccoms() {       
    var searchString = $('#searchval').val();
    $('span.acc-head').each(function(){
        var spanString = $(this).text();    
        if(spanString.search(searchString) == 1){
            console.log('found');
        }else{
            console.log('Not Found');
        }       
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="searchval" name="searchval">
<img src="images/icon_search.png" class="search-btn" type="submit" onclick="return searchAccoms();">
```

Scenario: I have following text in SPAN tag:

```
field
field
extra field
field1
field3
field2
```

Example SPAN:

```
<span id="18" class="acc-head"> field1</span>
```

When I search 'field' in the search box it works fine but when I search 'Field' the first letter in caps 'F' then it is not working. I am looking for `%Field%` like commend in MySQL.

Is there any other way to do the search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make both strings either lowercase or uppercase to make the search case insensitive:

```
function searchAccoms() {       
    var searchString = $('#searchval').val();

    $('span.acc-head').each(function(){
        var spanString = $(this).text();

        if (spanString.toLowerCase().search(searchString.toLowerCase()) == 1) {
            console.log('found');
        } else {
            console.log('Not Found');
        }       
    });
}
```

Another option would be to construct a regex, something like

```
var searchString = $('#searchval').val();
var regex = new RegExp(searchString, 'i');

...

if(spanString.search(regex) == 1)
```

but just making the strings the same case seems a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

I guess  `if(spanString.match(searchString))` should do the work even if it returns an array .